# AG-Grid Server Side Pagination paginationChanged Event

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, ag-grid-angular

I would like to implement AG-Grid with Server side Pagination

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    if(this.pageNumber == 0)
      this.pageNumber = 1;

    var datasource = {
      getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
        params.startRow = this.pageNumber;
        params.endRow = this.pageSize;
        this.test.getUsers(params)
          .subscribe(data => {
            params.successCallback(data['users'], data['totalRecords'])
          });
      }
    }
    this.rowData = datasource;
    this.gridApi.setDatasource(datasource);
}
```

onGridReady event works fine. But when moving to 2nd Page, I am not getting data. I have implemented pagination as below.

```
onPaginationChanged(event) {
    if (event.newPage) {
        
    }
}
```

And below is the URL to fetch data from Web API

```
getUsers(params) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8302/api/home/GetUsers?pageNumber=' + params.startRow + "&pageSize=" + params.endRow);
}
```

What should I write in onPaginationChanged event so that it fetches the next set of records and populates the data in 2nd page with 2nd set of records?

Comment: YES THIS! I am not sure what to do.You are using Partial store and server-side row model right?

Comment: Came to know that if I want to use Server Side Pagination with AG-Grid, I have to pay some amount for it to get License and then only it works!!